# Java to insert the input values into ArrayList and print sum of elements present at even index of the ArrayList using Iterator

Tags: java

I have written this code My Problem is it is taking the length. of array as input but not reading the elements of array We have to use iterator for reading all Inputs.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
public class arrayl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList < Integer > list = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
        System.out.println(" Enter the length of array :");

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter List : ");

        for (Iterator < Integer > itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
            if (itr.next() != null) {

                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Integer thisInt = itr.next();
                    if (thisInt % 2 == 0) {
                        list.add(thisInt);
                    }
                    System.out.println(" Even Index Position Sum : ");

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if you want elements at even index why are you using iterator simple for loop can do the job. And one more thing you are using iterator with for loop then why are you using while loop inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems according to the context you have asked.

1. You haven't added anything to the list yet using `scanner`. So, how can you get the values to be calculated?
2. Using two loops for iterating through the list and checking again, this does not seem correct.
3. Printing your final output inside the loop will print it several times.

So, here is the complete code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class arrayl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Enter the length of array :");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter List : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(sc.nextInt());
        }

        Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            int val = itr.next();
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                sum += val;
            }
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("Even Index Position Sum : " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added anything to the `ArrayList`, so your `for` loop doesn't do anything.  You have to add something to it first using `list.add(element)` where `element` is an `int`.